# Работа с сетью на канальном уровне

Tags: сеть, golang, пакет

Подскажите есть ли в go возможность отправлять сетевые пакеты к канальному уровню. Если есть то было бы здорово получить ссылку на источник.

Comment: Вам нужно уметь работать с драйвером сетевой карты. В Винде это ndis. В линуксе свое. Поэтому краткий ответ - используйте с/с++ и апи целевой системы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчет этой статьи?
https://mdlayher.com/blog/network-protocol-breakdown-ethernet-and-go/

Используется следюущий пакет для формирования и отправки фреймов:
[github.com/mdlayher/ethernet](https://github.com/mdlayher/ethernet)

Если Вам необходимо делать это на ОГРОМНЫХ скоростях, в таком случае, пригодится DPDK и Go-NFF, но они специфичны и работают на ограниченном железе:
[github.com/intel-go/nff-go](https://github.com/intel-go/nff-go)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. скажем, пример приведите. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]